# Force download of asset file from template

Tags: templating, assets, url, filesystem

I have a template called `download` that receives an asset ID, looks it up and should force the browser to download the file. I've gotten this far with the `{% headers %}` tag, but I can't figure out how to read the raw contents of the file and output it.

```
{% set asset = craft.assets.id(craft.request.getLastSegment()).first() %}
{% header 'Content-Description: File Transfer' %}
{% header 'Content-Type: '~asset.mimetype %}
{% header 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='~asset.filename %}
{% header 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' %}
{% header 'Expires: 0' %}
{% header 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' %}
{% header 'Pragma: public' %}
{% header 'Content-Length: '~asset.size %}
{# How to print raw contents of asset.url ??? #}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this out-of-the-box, but should be stupidly simple with a quick [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that registers its own Twig extension.  See [here](https://github.com/low/low_regex) for an example.

That extension would add a Twig function that's basically just a simple wrapper for PHP's [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Then from your template, you'd do something like:

```
{# Get the file contents #}
{% set contents = file('/path/to/asset.zip') %}

{# output it #}
{{ contents }}
```

Comment: For anyone looking, I'm using this plugin. I made my own fork so that environment variables are parsed properly. https://github.com/someoneandsons/craft-yii-sendfile

Comment: Ahh yeah... forgot we had a sendFile() method!

Comment: One thing the plugin wouldn't handle would be assets from external sources (S3 etc), but I think that's a job for another day. For my use case, this did the job.

Comment: @MikePierce I tried your plugin with asset from external links and it actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MikePierce I've been using your little plugin on one of my sites and it's been working great. However I've just switched the site to https:// and now the plugin fails. Any ideas?

Comment: @Lettie I haven't used it in a while, but just looked at the code. Only thing I could guess would be something in your config paths to the asset source. What do they look like on your set-up?